# Error when initiating Data Base in Apache Airflow

Tags: python, shell, terminal, airflow, alembic

I have built a local environment on my computer to test Dags in airflow however when I got to initiate the database in the terminal with airflow initdb I am prompted with an error message.

The message has to do with the package Alembic and reads `alembic.util.exc.CommandError: Can't locate revision identified by '939bb1e647c8'`

Any suggestions to fix?

Comment: Is this a fresh install?

Comment: @PirateNinjas yes I just installed it today.

Comment: A couple of things you might try: 1) run airflow dropdb and see if it works. I suspect this will also error. 2) check that the path to your database is correct. This would be in your airflow.cfg file most likely. You should also check where your airflow home is set to in the same file. If you get any errors could you post an update/edit?

Comment: @PirateNinjas, I fixed it! Had to reset the database in the config file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it by reentering the database path in the config file.

Comment: It might be helpful to add some details to this for future people stuck with the same error as you. What did you have in the cfg file originally and what did you change it to?